# Trouble configuring Autofac in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, autofac, asp.net-core-2.0

I started of with my first .NET CORE 2.0 project which would be a webapi. So far so good until I ran into the issue trying to configure Autofac. I followed the instructions described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection). But unfortunately I get build errors in my StartUp. Apparently `ContainerBuilder` does not contain the definition of `Populate()`. Also the type `AutofacServiceProvider` could not be found. I've search the net for some time, trying to find the correct documentation for 2.0. It's scattered and not always clear if the source is targeting 1.0 or 2.0. Unfortunately all options end up with build error so I thought I'd stick with the implementation provided by the official documentation. Is it possible that Autofac does not support this form of initiation in .NET Core 2.0.

FYI:

```
using Autofac;
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace TEST.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
            containerBuilder.RegisterModule<ServiceModule>();
            containerBuilder.Populate(services);
            var container = containerBuilder.Build();
            return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}


<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Model\Recipy.Model.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Service\Recipy.Service.csproj" />  
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.6.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Why are you using Autofac instead of the built-in DI framework?

Comment: Because of the modules, and I have worked with it in the past. :)

Comment: Jonathan, you need a different container if you e.g. use NancyFx.

Comment: @norgie, can u give more pointers on NancyFx + Core 2.1 + Autofac, it helps

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fairly easy solution to this,
both the Populate method and the AutofacServiceProvider are in a namespace you arent using at the moment.

You also need "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection"

and then those two issues should resolve

Comment: Well that is a bit shameful. VSCode did not  give a suggestion for adding a reference so I rulled that out which is stupid of me.I thank you sir for your insight. :)